# How to pass a function down the component's hierarchy without using props in React?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have component hierarchy A, B, C. 
Is there a way to call a function of A from C without using props? The thing is: Is it possible to exclude the intermediary B from the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is a solution, but may be a bad idea, especially if you're new to React.

Try to resolve your issue using ES6 the `...rest` operator, like the following:

```
const A = ({ arg1, arg2 = 4, ...rest }) => (
  <B size={arg1 * arg2} {...rest} />
);


const B = ({size, size = {}, ...rest}) => (
  <C {...rest} style={style} />
);
```

This is a raw example, the idea is that C gets everything B is given, but B wouldn't know all those params and would just provide them. Here B provides `style` but doesn't know `style` is given to him. But C knows he could get `size`, and therefore use it.

This alternative is much better than using Context if you don't know how Context works. You should first try with this rest thing rather than Context.

Context is really useful sometimes, but generally, you must know what you're doing.

*Note that this solution needs ES6, so you'll need Babel or equivalent to transpile the code.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to achievie this. According to react docs it allows to:

> pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props
>   down manually at every level.

Comment: Just to elaborate on that: by implementing `getChildContext()` and defining `childContextTypes` on A, you could make the function available in any descendant component by using `contextTypes`. It is not mandatory for this to be maintained all through the hierarchy.

Comment: Example [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-implicitly-via-context) and warning [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context)

Comment: In the same link that you posted, it is recommended not to use context. `If you want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React.`

Comment: that's why I wrote that there is a warning

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Pass the function of A as props to B then pass the same props as props to C.Then can call the function as follows:

```
this.props.someFunction();
```

Comment: The question was how to do this without passing down props :)